# Why is $p^m \leq 2n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My book says that if $L=\text{LCM}(1,2,...,2n)$, then for every prime $p$ that divides $L$, the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $L$, $m$, is also the largest integer such that $p^m \leq 2n$. Why?

Comment: Think about the prime factorizations of $1,2,\ldots,2n$. Could one of them have a power of $p$ *greater* than $2n$?

Comment: I think it'd be best to do an example. Perhaps say $L=LCM(1,\dots,100)$. The prime factorization of $L$ is $2^a\cdot 3^b\cdot 5^c\cdot 7^d\cdots 97^{y}$. Is it clear why there are no other primes in the list? And then, what could $a$ be? Could it be 1? 2? 3? Why must it be 6?